# Unable to retrieve the webpage programatically

Tags: blackberry, html

I wrote a simple program in that retrieves google home page. the code is below:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
    InputStream data = conn.openInputStream();
    StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int nRead = data.read(buf);
    while(nRead > 0){
        raw.append(new String(buf, 0, nRead));
        nRead = data.read(buf);
    }
    dest.updateDestination(raw.toString());

}
else
    dest.updateDestination("responseCode="+ Integer.toString(responseCode));            
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        dest.updateDestination("Exception:"+e.toString());
    }
```

This is my main screen:

```
MenuItem getDataAction = new MenuItem("GetData", 100, 10){
        public void run(){
            String URL = "http://www.google.com";
            ServiceRequestThread svc = new ServiceRequestThread(URL, (MyScreen)
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
            svc.start();
        }
    };
    addMenuItem(getDataAction);
}

public void updateDestination(final String text){
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            output.setText(text);
        }
    });
}
```

When i am running my application on the simulator, i am getting the exception that is caught as  **Exception:java.io.IOException:Radio is Off** I am using eclipse IDE. Should i change any properties in the eclipse or simulator. why am i getting this exception. What is the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simulator menu, go to Simulate -> Network Properties and look at the available networks to make sure "In Coverage" is ticked. Also in on the simulated device, go to the Manage Connections menu and make sure you have the Mobile Network enabled.

Comment: Now i am getting the output as responsecode:302. Again why this is happening. Thank you atleast it came upto here

Comment: HTTP code 302 is redirection. It should be giving you the address of where the redirection is pointing, so if you follow that you should have the correct page.

Comment: Sorry Can you explain me a little more

Comment: Don't know if you've gotten further on this or not, but the here's a link that should help explain what a 302 means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302